# Angular 4 - white background when I want navigate to home

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-router

I want the routing to move me to the home page when the authorization returns false, that's how the link changes to the main page, but the screen is all white, I need to refresh the page to get a component

I have this code

Auth:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor (private serwis: SerwisService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.serwis.login === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
  }
}
```

Routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
```

Please look at the photo, this is what happens after the redirection by authorization to the main page

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to redirect to '/'?:  this.router.navigate(['/']); Or adding to the routing: patchMatch: 'full' in the first item?

Comment: ` this.router.navigate(['']);` won't be executed cause it's after the `return`

Comment: I try now but it does not work

Comment: It's true, my bad :D, I changed before return and it works, thanks